# Tkinter buttons not changing back to the correct color after state changing to active

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making this PDF tool, and I want the buttons to be disabled until a file or files are successfully imported. This is what the app looks like at the launch:[image: Disabled State]

Right after running the callback for the import files button, the active state looks like this:
[image: Active State]

I want the colors of the buttons to turn maroon instead of the original grey. They only turn back to maroon once you hover the mouse over them. Any thoughts for how to fix this? Here is the callback for the import button:

```
def import_callback():
    no_files_selected = False
    global files
    files = []
    try:
        ocr_button['state'] = DISABLED
        merge_button['state'] = DISABLED
        status_label.pack_forget()
        frame.pack_forget()
        files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
        for f in files:
            name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
            if extension != '.pdf':
                raise
        if not files:
            no_files_selected = True
            raise

        if frame.winfo_children():
            for label in frame.winfo_children():
                label.destroy()
        make_import_file_labels(files)
        frame.pack()

        ocr_button['state'] = ACTIVE
        merge_button['state'] = ACTIVE
    except:
        if no_files_selected:
            status_label.config(text='No files selected.', fg='blue')
        else:
            status_label.config(text='Error: One or more files is not a PDF.', fg='red')
        status_label.pack(expand='yes')


import_button = Button(root, text='Import Files', width=scaled(20), bg='#5D1725', bd=0, fg='white', relief='groove',
                       command=import_callback)
import_button.pack(pady=scaled(50))
```

Comment: Have you tried to call something like "self.update()"  after set the config, where self is your frame?

Comment: @1966bc there are rare cases to call `update` rather use `update_idletasks`. Anyway this won't do a difference since there are no methods to achive the goals.

Comment: @1966bc I tried the update method on the root and each button, but not really sure what it does or how it is useful. The only frame that I am using is for the file name labels that you see under the merge button in the second picture. The merge and ocr button and everything else is packed into the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you right you want something like:

```
...
ocr_button['state'] = DISABLED
ocr_button['background'] = '#*disabled background*'
ocr_button.bind('<Enter>', lambda e:ocr_button.configure(background='#...'))
ocr_button.bind('<Leave>', lambda e:ocr_button.configure(background='#...'))

merge_button['state'] = DISABLED
merge_button['background'] = '#*disabled background*'
merge_button.bind('<Enter>', lambda e:ocr_button.configure(background='#...'))
merge_button.bind('<Leave>', lambda e:ocr_button.configure(background='#...'))
...

...
ocr_button['state'] = ACTIVE
ocr_button['background'] = '#*active background*'
ocr_button.unbind('<Enter>')
ocr_button.unbind('<Leave>')

merge_button['state'] = ACTIVE
merge_button['background'] = '#*active background*'
merge_button.unbind('<Enter>')
merge_button.unbind('<Leave>')
...
```

If there are any errors, since I wrote it out of my mind or something isnt clear, let me know.

**Update**

the following code reproduces the behavior as you stated. The reason why this happens is how tkinter designed the standart behavior. You will have a better understanding of it if you consider [style of ttk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938796/13629335) widgets. So I would recommand to dont use the automatically design by `state` rather write a few lines of code to configure your buttons how you like, add and delete the commands and change the background how you like. If you dont want to write this few lines you would be forced to use `ttk.Button` and **map** a behavior you do like

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def func_b1():
    print('func of b1 is running')
def disable_b1():
    b1.configure(bg='grey', command='')
def activate_b1():
    b1.configure(bg='red', command=func_b1)


b1 = tk.Button(root,text='B1', bg='red',command=func_b1)
b2 = tk.Button(root,text='disable', command=disable_b1)
b3 = tk.Button(root,text='activate',command=activate_b1)

b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want the merge button and ocr button to look exactly like the import button in the first picture once the import button callback is complete. But right now, after the import button callback, the merge and ocr button only revert back to looking like the import button once you hover over them with the mouse. It's odd because I didn't create and binds nor do I want to unless binds are somehow the solution.

Comment: @GabeMorris this is more or less the normal behavior of the buttons. I add an example and an explanation of it.

Comment: That is the same behavior. It appears that when a button is made active, it reverts the background to the original gray. I need to make it to where the user can't call the merge and ocr button callbacks until the 'files' variable is not None. I guess I'll just have to raise an exception in my ocr/merge callbacks if files is None. But what do you mean about deleting a command?

Comment: @GabeMorris So I made functions to disable the `b1` and activate it again. So you could add these functions into your code instead or in addtion of using the option `state` which messes up your design.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. I tried your logic and it worked. Just start the buttons off with an empty command and configure the command in the import files callback as well as change the color. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this was asked quite a while ago, so probably already solved for the user. But since I had the exact same problem and do not see the "simplest" answer here, I thought I would post:

Just change the state from "active" to "normal"

```
ocr_button['state'] = NORMAL
merge_button['state'] = NORMAL
```

I hope this helps future users!

Comment: How simple is this!!! Incredible.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote this simple app that I think could help all to reproduce the problem.

Notice that the state of the button when you click is Active.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Main(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()


        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def cols_configure(self, w):

        w.columnconfigure(0, weight=0,  minsize=100)
        w.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        
        w.rowconfigure(0, weight=0, minsize=50)
        w.rowconfigure(1, weight=0,)
        
        

    def get_init_ui(self, container):
        
        w = ttk.Frame(container, padding=5)
        self.cols_configure(w)
        w.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)

        return w        
          
    def init_ui(self):

        w = self.get_init_ui(self.parent)

        r = 0
        c = 0
        
        b = ttk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="", relief=tk.GROOVE, padding=5)
   
        self.btn_import = tk.Button(b,
                                    text="Import Files",
                                    underline=1,
                                    command = self.on_import,
                                    bg='#5D1725',
                                    bd=0,
                                    fg='white')
        self.btn_import.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E,padx=5, pady=5)
          
        self.parent.bind("<Alt-i>", self.switch)

        r +=1

        self.btn_ocr = tk.Button(b,
                                    text="OCR FIles",
                                    underline=0,
                                    command = self.on_ocr,
                                    bg='#5D1725',
                                    bd=0,
                                    fg='white')

        self.btn_ocr["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        
        self.btn_ocr.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E,padx=5, pady=5)

        r +=1

        self.btn_merge = tk.Button(b,
                                    text="Merge Files",
                                    underline=0,
                                    command = self.on_merge,
                                    bg='#5D1725',
                                    bd=0,
                                    fg='white')

        self.btn_merge["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        
        self.btn_merge.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E,padx=5, pady=5)
          
        r +=1

        self.btn_reset = tk.Button(b,
                                    text="Reset",
                                    underline=0,
                                    command = self.switch,
                                    bg='#5D1725',
                                    bd=0,
                                    fg='white')
        self.btn_reset.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.E,padx=5, pady=5)
          
        
        b.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)


    def on_import(self, evt=None):
        
        self.switch()
        #simulate some import
        self.after(5000, self.switch())
        
        
    def switch(self,):

        state = self.btn_import["state"]
        
        if state == tk.ACTIVE:
            self.btn_import["state"] = tk.DISABLED
            self.btn_ocr["state"] = tk.NORMAL
            self.btn_merge["state"] = tk.NORMAL
            
        else:
            self.btn_import["state"] = tk.NORMAL
            self.btn_ocr["state"] = tk.DISABLED
            self.btn_merge["state"] = tk.DISABLED
            
           
    def on_ocr(self, evt=None):
        state = self.btn_ocr["state"]
        print ("ocr button state is {0}".format(state))
        
        

    def on_merge(self, evt=None):
        state = self.btn_merge["state"]
        print ("merge button state is {0}".format(state))
        
        
    def on_close(self, evt=None):
        self.parent.on_exit()

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Main Application start here"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)
        self.set_style()
        self.set_title(kwargs['title'])
            
        
        Main(self, *args, **kwargs)
       
    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")
        

    def set_title(self, title):
        s = "{0}".format('Simple App')
        self.title(s)
        
    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()

def main():

    args = []

    for i in sys.argv:
        args.append(i)

    kwargs = {"style":"clam", "title":"Simple App",}

    app = App(*args, **kwargs)

    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]